# TortoiseSVN Update Error: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are having trouble with TortoiseSVN when updating. We are getting

**Error: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression**

After running the recommended cleanup if we execute a new update the update will just hold or throw this same error again. If the update holds, we have seen it hold for hours, we have to just cancel the update.

The configuration of the system is as follows

- Windows 7 64-bit
- TortoiseSVN 1.8.11, Build 26392 - 64 Bit , 2015/03/19 18:50:20
- Subversion 1.8.13, -release
- apr 1.5.1
- apr-util 1.5.4
- serf 1.3.8
- OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
- zlib 1.2.8

Any input regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.